# Entity Framework code first outer join for interesting schema

Tags: database-design, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, entity-relationship

So I have a schema I've developed that has a table that acts a junction table for multiple entities.  This is for the purpose of tagging.  I have my entities use GUIDs and then I'm able to centralize the tagging.

[image]

In this case in the diagram, I'm relating a TeamMember via TeamMemberGUID in a many to many setup via the ObjectTag junction table a 'la the ObjectGUID field.  I could just as easily relate any other GUID keyed entity in the same way.  Thus I have a central repo of tags that can "tag" various entities.  Pretty slick, or so I *thought*.

The trouble is I can't seem to find a way to bring this data back with LINQ to Entities.  I'm using EF Code First and I want to bring this back in one query if possible.  The closest I've gotten is using ugly outer join syntax:

```
var team = from tm in db.TeamMembers
join ot in db.ObjectTags on tm.TeamMemberGuid equals ot.ObjectGuid into objTags  // outer join to ObjectTag

from ot2 in objTags.DefaultIfEmpty()
join tags in db.Tags on ot2.TagId equals tags.TagId into tmTags  // join via ObjectTag to Tag

select new TeamMemberDTO
{
     TeamMember = tm,
     Tags = tmTags
};
```

But this gives me a flattened set (4 team members sharing 2 tags can equal up to 8 results) where what I'm looking for is a hierarchical TeamMember object with a Tags property of the associated tags.

I've tried normal relation properties but EF doesn't want to map more than one entity to a junction table so that's out.  I've also tried a group by but haven't gotten far with that.

Is this out for LINQ to EF?  Do I need to consider a view or something?

Really hoping an EF pro can help me on this one.  I feel like I'm missing something or taking the wrong approach.